# How to start with Scala, intelliJ IDEA and SBT?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I downloaded IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3, SBT, Scala and SBT plugins, set environment variables correctly, i guess (if i can run Scala repl is it correct?)

When i start IntelliJ IDEA and choose new SBT-based project i get some problems:

1) no /src/ folder in project structure. How i can fix that?

2) can't compile manually created Scala file: IDEA suggest me edit configuration with Alt+Shift+F10 then i get window with various settings, so what directly should i edit?

Sorry for possibly stupid questions, but i just want to run miserable

"hello world" in Scala...

Comment: The Scala plugin gives you a SBT console i.e. a repl environment so there is no need to install anything other than the Intellij Scala plugin. I would uninstall any other SBT type plugins to make sure they are not interfering.

Comment: maybe is the SBT download slowly,me too. i also cann't find src directory.

Comment: @user866667, are you using the latest version of Intellij? If not I highly recommend it as it has a setup wizard to get the IDE Scala enabled from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any extra plugins besides the Scala plugin. Assuming you have that installed, then

**Step One: Fire up IntelliJ and Click on "Create New Project"**

[image]

**Step Two: Choose Scala from the left hand side panel and choose SBT on the right hand side panel (i.e SBT-based Scala project) and click Next.**

[image]

**Step Three: Fill in your project details and click Finish**

[image]

**Step Four: Wait for Intellij to download all SBT dependencies and to construct the folder structure and to index.**

[image]

**Step Five: Begin hacking!**

Comment: Unfortunately, my project structure no looks like yours: http://imgur.com/tFUsazV

and SBT dont want to start http://imgur.com/ZCiJBpC

Comment: It seems then your environment is not quite right. What I would do is uninstall Intellij, remove the .Idea folder and the reinstall Intellij and the Scala plugin **ONLY**. Make sure you don't have any environment variables pointing to a local scala or sbt installation.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't have any effect.